# Do DDR3 SODIMM modules come in sizes greater than 8GB?

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3, sodimm

I'm really interested on buying a 1x16GB DDR3 SODIMM module because my laptop has only one memory slot. I know that DIMM modules with 16GB do exist. But I can find only packs with two 8GB modules of SODIMM. So, where can I find such a module if it exists ?

The laptop I want to upgrade is an Asus UX32VD with 2GB of DDR3 memory on mother board (can't change it), and 1 slot. I upgraded it to 10GB (2+8).

Comment: Desktop memory; yes they exist; but on a laptop the chipset is different;  if you can't find it then it's not sold.

Comment: What specifically make and model is your laptop?  If they just started making them, if you laptop will support these modules, you will very likely need to update its firmware/bios.

Comment: Probably not a good question as it will become obsolete quickly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they only recently did.

However, if you are using an Intel processor from 2013 or earlier then you may not be able to utilize 16GB sodimms.

The only exception is the Atom C2xxx series Avoton.

The i3, i5, i7 Sandybridge, Ivybridge, Haswell processors all can take only 8GB UDIMMs or SO-DIMMs.

Not sure about the latest generation of Intel processors though.

On AMD platforms, the [Intelligent Memory](http://www.intelligentmemory.com/dram-modules/ddr3-so-dimm/) 16GB modules are said to work fine.

Comment: It generally is not the processor, but the BIOS/Chipset/Firmware that limits the addressable size of memory module.

Comment: Given that the memory controller is 'on-die' of most modern processors, it is now the main factor that limits any memory sizes.

Comment: @David: In the case of Intel processors, it is the MRC code in the BIOS that needs to be updated to support 16GB unregistered DIMMs.

Answer (score 0):

An example Haswell:

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/78939/intel-core-i7-4910mq-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html

- Max 2 slots
- Max 32 GB (I assume that's 16 GB x 2, not 32 GB per slot)
- 1333 or 1600 DDR3L/PC3L (L is low power version, is low voltage)

Side notes:

DDR3L is 1.35V low power, regular DDR3 1.5V

On my laptop I know that regular DDR3 non-low power works. So the processor can do 1.5V. And I've subsequently A/B tested both DDR3 and DDR3L across 4910mq, 4810mq, 4710mq and others across several HP J series motherboards and a Clevo w650 motherboard. It's clearly supported in actuality electrically, though its not on the spec sheet. So at your own risk. 1.5V in most cases is slightly faster.  I hit these very very hard with testing and real loads over long periods.

I've never tried 16GB module, but I stumbled across this looking to buy a 16GB module. Wanted to share what I knew for future travelers. If I buy one I'll report back.